# random walk using RecurrenceTable

Tags: evaluation, random, recursion

I'm trying to generate a random walk using RecurrenceTable:

```
RecurrenceTable[
  {a[n + 1] == RandomVariate[  NormalDistribution[a[n], 0.5`]] , a[1] == 10},
  a, {n, 1, 10}]
```

The above (simplified example) code works (in version 10.3), but I get two errors:

```
RandomVariate::realprm: Parameter a[n] at position 1 in NormalDistribution[a[n],0.5] is expected to be real. 
RandomVariate::realprm: "Parameter #2 at position 1 in NormalDistribution[#2,0.5] is expected to be real."
```

I suspect that this is because mathematica is attempting to evaluate NormalDistribution immediately, but should only be doing so once `a[n]` is evaluatable to a number.

Whats the right way to correct this error?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This works..

```
f[x_?NumericQ] := RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[x, 0.5`]]
RecurrenceTable[{a[n + 1] == f[a[n]], a[1] == 10}, a, {n, 1, 10}]
```

> {10, 9.01261, 8.63581, 8.92847, 9.097, 9.48324, 9.44516, 8.19759, 
>   8.01132, 8.85788}

I don't see why you don't just do this though:

```
NestList[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[#, 0.5`]] &, 10, 10]
```

Comment: Excellent!  As to why i'm not using NestList, it's because I didn't know it existed.  I will now.